# Extracting 'n' characters from a column of a dataframe, based on 'find' results (Using str.contains() & str.find() with df.loc[]

Tags: python, pandas

If column 'id' contains "(Slot" then slot no. should be extracted in 'Output' column from the 'id' column else if column 'id' contains "PR GRP" then 1st slot no. should be extracted in 'Output' column from the 'grp' column. Positions of Slot No. are fixed i.e in 1st case need to extract 7 characters from the location where '(Slot" found and then remove '(' to get the slot no. In 2nd case 1st Slot No. would always be found at 6th place and will have 6 characters as well.

```
id                            grp                              Output
Alpha-old-1_MOD (Slot01)      -                                Slot01
Alpha-old-1_PR GRP1           MOD (Slot07);MOD (Slot08)        Slot07
Beta-new-1_PR GRP2            MOD (Slot13);MOD (Slot14)        Slot13
Beta-old-1_MOD (Slot03)       -                                Slot03
```

Expected output:

[image: Input & Output Table]]

[Input & Output Table for Query No. 2 & 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Abo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `str.extract` and `str.split`:

```
df["output"] = df["id"].str.extract("(Slot\d+)").fillna(df["grp"].str.extract("(Slot\d+)"))
df["status"] = df["id"].str.split("_MOD|_PR GRP").str[0].str.split("-").str[1]
df["name"] = df["id"].str.split("_MOD|_PR GRP").str[0]

>>> df
                         id                        grp  output status  \
0  Alpha-old-1_MOD (Slot01)                          -  Slot01    old   
1       Alpha-old-1_PR GRP1  MOD (Slot07);MOD (Slot08)  Slot07    old   
2        Beta-new-1_PR GRP2  MOD (Slot13);MOD (Slot14)  Slot13    new   
3   Beta-old-1_MOD (Slot03)                          -  Slot03    old   

          name  
0  Alpha-old-1  
1  Alpha-old-1  
2   Beta-new-1  
3   Beta-old-1
```

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression to look for the word Slot follow by 2 digits

```
import re

data="""id\tgrp
Alpha-old-1_MOD (Slot01)\t-
Alpha-old-1_PR GRP1\tMOD (Slot07);MOD (Slot08)
Beta-new-1_PR GRP2\tMOD (Slot13);MOD (Slot14)
Beta-old-1_MOD (Slot03)\t-
"""



df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),sep='\t')

pattern=r"[\s\w\(]+(Slot{1}\d{2})+[\s\w\)]+"

df['output']=''
for key,row in df.iterrows():
    if re.search("PR GRP",str(row['id'])):
        matches=re.findall(pattern,str(row['grp']))
    else:
        matches=re.findall(pattern,str(row['id']))
    if len(matches)>0:
        df.loc[key,'output']=matches[0]

print(df[['id','grp','output']])
```

output:

```
                         id                        grp            output
0  Alpha-old-1_MOD (Slot01)                          -          [Slot01]
1       Alpha-old-1_PR GRP1  MOD (Slot07);MOD (Slot08)          [Slot07]
2        Beta-new-1_PR GRP2  MOD (Slot13);MOD (Slot14)          [Slot13]
3   Beta-old-1_MOD (Slot03)                          -          [Slot03]
```